# How does this os x bash script that emulates linux's readlink work?

Tags: linux, macos, bash, shell

[From superuser](https://superuser.com/a/218684/291415):

```
function abspath() {
  pushd . > /dev/null;
  if [ -d "$1" ]; then
    cd "$1";
    dirs -l +0;
  else
    cd "`dirname \"$1\"`";
    cur_dir=`dirs -l +0`;
    if [ "$cur_dir" == "/" ]; then
      echo "$cur_dir`basename \"$1\"`";
    else
      echo "$cur_dir/`basename \"$1\"`";
    fi;
  fi;
  popd > /dev/null;
}
```

I want to use this script, but I'm wary of using something I don't fully understand.

Comment: You need to find the function `dirs` to know what it does.

Comment: you can also copy/paste each line/block of code into a terminal window. Use `set -x` to show expansion of variables. Use `set -- "/your/dir/of/interest"` to set a value for `$1`. Good luck.

Comment: Also, it is neither hard to write a program that is equivalent to the `readlink` command nor hard to get the GNU version of `readlink` and install it on your Mac.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Besides the small detail that it does not really syntactically nor semantically emulate the `readlink(1)/stat(1)` command, you will get all the information you desire by invoking `man bash` and searching for the `dirs`, `pushd`, and `popd` builtin documentation therein. The `basename` and `dirname` commands have respective man pages as well, which explain the commands' functionalities much better than I would.

Having said this, let's describe your referred script somewhat:

```
 1  function abspath() {
 2    pushd . > /dev/null;
 3    if [ -d "$1" ]; then
 4      cd "$1";
 5      dirs -l +0;
 6    else
 7      cd "`dirname \"$1\"`";
 8      cur_dir=`dirs -l +0`;
 9      if [ "$cur_dir" == "/" ]; then
10        echo "$cur_dir`basename \"$1\"`";
11      else
12        echo "$cur_dir/`basename \"$1\"`";
13      fi;
14    fi;
15    popd > /dev/null;
16  }
```

Some explanations:

```
 1) Define a shell function
 2) Add current working directory to the directory stack and change to it
 3) If the submitted parameter corresponds to a directory
 4) Change to it
 5) Show full pathname of the current working directory
 6) otherwise [if the submitted parameter is not a directory]
 7) strip away the filename portion, beginning with the last slash `/' character to the end of string and change into the directory
 8) Store the full pathname of the current working directory into the `cur_dir` variable
 9) if the current working directory is '/' then 
10) output the full qualified path using the cur_dir variable and the base name of the submitted parameter
11) otherwise
12) output the full qualified path using the cur_dir variable, a `/', and the base name of the submitted parameter
13) end of inner if block
14) end of outer if block
15) remove current working directory from directory stack and change back it, essentially moving back to the originating directory from where we called the function from.
16) close shell function definition
```

Together with the man pages and the respective bash builtin documentation, you should understand the inner workings of this shell function.